# Undefined property: CI_Loader::$input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just started to learn CodeIgniter and gotten trouble with example below:
 My Controller:

```
      class Site extends CI_Controller 
      {
        public function __construct()
    {

         parent::__construct();
    }
    function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('options_view');
    }
        function create()
    {
    $data = array (
     'title' => $this->load->input->post('title'),
     'content' => $this->load->input->post('content')
    );
     $this->site_model->add_record($data);
     $this->index();
    }
      }
```

My Model is:

```
    class Site_model extends CI_Model
    {
     function get_records()
     {
     $q = $this->db->get('articles');
     return $q->result();
     }
    function add_record($data)
     { 
      $this->db->insert('articles',$data);
      return;
     }
    }
```

My view is:

```
<pre>
       <?php echo form_open('site/create');?>
    <p>
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
    </p>
     <p>
      <label for="content">Content:</label> 
      <input type="text" name="content" id="content"/> 
      </p>
      <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
      </p>
      <?php echo form_close();?>
</pre>
```

So when I click Submit button I get the error like:
 
    `Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$input
    Filename: controllers/site.php
    Line Number: 19`

Any ideas will be usefull!Thanx!!

Answer (score 3):

try this in your contorller.

```
 class Site extends CI_Controller 
      {
        public function __construct()
    {

         parent::__construct();
    }
    function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('options_view');
    }
        function create()
    {
    $data = array (
     'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
     'content' => $this->input->post('content')
    );
     $this->site_model->add_record($data);
     $this->index();
    }
      }
```

no need of using load in front of the input statement in the function create.
Try it..

Comment: no mention, if you think it's the answer,then you can accept the enswer. :D

Answer (score 1):

The lines should be like

```
'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
'content' => $this->input->post('content')
```

not

```
'title' => $this->load->input->post('title'),
'content' => $this->load->input->post('content')
```

and also you need to load the form helper.so after parent::__construct(); add this line or you can add in your autoload.php page

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: OK! Thanx, I'm using $autoload['helper']